# Join 2 tables, display one column and group by same column

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

1. [CompanyGroups] (id,id_company,id_group)
2. [CompanyRegions] (id,id_company,id_region)

I want to select only id_company where (id_group in (...) or id_region in (..))

```
Select g.id_company, r.id_company
from CompanyGroups g, CompanyRegions r
where (g.id_group in (...) or r.id_region in (...)) group by id_company
```

The results are in 2 columns: g.id_company has some ids and r.id_company has others ids.

How to grup them in only 1 column?

Comment: Use Union of two queries, each selecting id_company from each table satisfying the conditions you specified, instead of aggregating fields from two tables in a single query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learnt Database concept quite long ago. So I try to recall those concept and answer what I remember to your question.

You are joining two tables without specifying any joining relationships between them. Then you select fields from each table, so the MySQL will join the two table by mapping each record from `CompanyGroups` to each record from `CompanyRegions`.

To solve your problem, you should use `UNION` instead.

```
SELECT id_company
FROM CompanyGroups 
WHERE id_group in (...)

UNION

SELECT id_company 
FROM CompanyRegions
WHERE id_region in (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by sagi might result in duplicates so I would extend the answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id_company 
FROM (
SELECT g.id_company FROM CompanyGroup g
WHERE g.id_group in(...)
UNION
SELECT r.id_company FROM CompanyRegions r
WHERE r.id_region in(...) 
) a
```